# C++: Picking out something from an array

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm quite new to programming so sorry if anything I say doesn't make sense!
I am currently trying to make a program and have found myself stuck in a little problem. I've made an array called `choice`, `choice[0] = one` , `choice[1] = two`.
When I ask a user something e.g.

I want to be able to get the user to pick out what they want from the array

```
cout << "Which would you like? Enter '0' for one, enter '1' for two " << endl;
cin >> choice
```

I understand the `cin >> choice` part is wrong but I don't know what to put, any suggestions would be amazing, thanks!

Okay some example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#inclue <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
string choice[2], userchoice;

choice[0] = "Red";
choice[1] = "Blue";

cout << "Type '0' to choose red, type '1' to choose blue" << endl;
cin >> userchoice;
cout << "You chose " << choice[userchoice] << endl;
}
```

I would like it to then print out "You chose red" or "You chose blue" just from them typing in either '0' or '1'

Comment: Please add some code (or format it correctly), otherwise at least I) can not help you

Comment: So, when the user inputs 0, you want it to print "one", and when the user input 1, you want it to print "two"?

Comment: You should study more about basic types. it looks like choice is an array, you can cin into a double or a int, but certainly not into an array.

Comment: You are missing a semicolon at the end of `string choice[2]`, and you don't define a `userchoice` variable anywhere. Perhaps at this point it would be better to study some basics first. Try to write programs that work with hard-coded numbers and values, *then* try to replace those with user input!

Comment: That code was just quickly written up by me, not copied from the program itself, I do have a semicolon at the end of string choice[2], and I also define userchoice in my program also

Comment: Just make userchoice not a string, but an `int` or `size_t`

Comment: yea I did that, thanks :) got it solved now, used a couple of if statements.

Comment: There are so many errors in your example code, how can you expect it to work? It would work just fine if you could correct those errors. example errors: #inclue <string>, string choice[2], userchoice; userchoice here can't be a string. I have posted a refined version of your example....

Answer (score 2):

You want the input to be the index into the array, so something like:

```
size_t index;
cout << "Which would you like? Enter '0' for one, enter '1' for two " << endl;
cin >> index;
cout << "\nYou chose: " << choice[index] << endl;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I tried what you put and it says
error: no operator "[]" matches these operands
operand types are std::string[2] [std::string]

Comment: @HelpIsNeeded: Then `choice` is not what your code made us believe it was. This code will work, for example, with `std::string choice[2];`.

Comment: Added some example code to the main post to try and make it clearer what I would like my program to do :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

string arr[5] = { "one" , "two" , "three" , "four" , "five" };

string returnArrayPos( int pos )
{
    if( pos >= 0 && pos < ( sizeof( arr ) / sizeof( *arr ) ) )
        return arr[pos];
    else
        return "Wrong Index!";
}

int main() {
    int pos = 0;

    cin >> pos;
    cout << returnArrayPos( pos ) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Bit more advanced solution to your question. And save for entering a wrong index.

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#inclue <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
string choice[2];
int userschoice;

choice[0] = "Red";
choice[1] = "Blue";

cout << "Type '0' to choose red, type '1' to choose blue" << endl;
cin >> userschoice;
if(userschoice == 0)
{
cout << "You chose " << choice[0] << endl;
}
else if(userschoice == 1)
{
cout << "You chose " << choice[1] << endl;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
string choice[2];
int userchoice;

choice[0] = "Red";
choice[1] = "Blue";

cout << "Type '0' to choose red, type '1' to choose blue" << endl;
cin >> userchoice;
if(userchoice>1) cout<<"Sorry my vocabulary isn't large enough..";
else
cout << "You chose " << choice[userchoice] << endl;
return 0;}
```